# Vertically align text (bottom) with Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

So let's say I have the following:

```
  <div class="row-fluid container">
    <div class="span2">
      <image of height 100px>
    </div>
    <div class="span10 inner"> 
      <span class="title">some title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I style this to get the title to align at the bottom of the span10 div?

**UPDATE**

Please provide an answer that will keep the responsive behavior of Bootstrap intact. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide CSS?

Comment: There is no CSS that is working.. I just left some class names in to help. I have changed them to make it easier

Comment: `span10` does not exist in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Also, `class="row-fluid container"` is incorrect. A div can't be both a row and a container. Nest the row div inside a container div instead.

Comment: Im not actually using the class name container. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given below are the styles you need.

```
.move-down2 {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.title {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nadeeth/6vmu0s6x/

Comment: I tried that, but when the screen resizes the title overlaps the image

Comment: As in, this fiddle would not work in the context of bootstrap responsive styling

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
.inner {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xoetoduj/

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working for me either.. maybe another bootstrap css conflict?

Comment: Is your project online? Give us a link or some more code :) I am working with bootstrap too, so I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the main div `display:table;` and the child div `display:table-cell;` then use `vertical-align:baseline;` or `vertical-align:bottom;` depending on your situation.

That usually helps with vertical aligning issues where you can't use line-height.

Alternatively you could use the below for a different approach if all images are 100px. I've colour the divs to illustrate.

```
.row-fluid {
    background-color:blue;
}
#yourimage {
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.span10 {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
}
```

Comment: I need something that doesn't kill the responsive behavior of bootstrap

Comment: This shouldn't kill any responsiveness. I use it all the time for centering text in divs for fully responsive sites. Not tried it with bootstrap but works with our CSS. Using display:table; has no negative responsive effects on well organised code so it should work fine.

Comment: Did you add display:table; to the highest div in the hierarchy? ie rowfluid container? I'd add an id to that div. Do you have the page it's on? You might have another conflict

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry not too sure. Maybe you can show your answer in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

we can use vertical align property in CSS to get bottom

http://jsfiddle.net/jai17/a7n89zcq/

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid move-down">
    <div class="span2">
      <image of height 100px>
    </div>
    <div class="span10 move-down2"> 
      <span class="title">some title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.move-down2 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 200px;
}
.title {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```